# how can I change my location while trying to scrape the website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am working on a website that is not showing any product if the visitor not in Turkey. The website is [Carrefoursa](https://www.carrefoursa.com/). When I try to scrape with my computer it is okay because of my location in Turkey. My server is located in Germany and the spider doesn't work on the server because of location. I already try a method as follow:

***I try to send it with Request***

```
class CarrefoursaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'carrefoursa'
    allowed_domains = ['www.carrefoursa.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.carrefoursa.com/meyve/c/1015']
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE":"scrapy_logs/"+name+".log",
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY":False,
        "USER_AGENTS":None,
        "COOKIES_ENABLED":True,
        "COOKIES_DEBUG" : True
        }
    def parse(self,reponse):
        request = scrapy.Request(
                reponse.url, callback=self.parse_product,cookies={'Content-Language':'tr','currency': 'TRY', 'country': 'TR','lang': 'tr'}, dont_filter=True)
        yield request
        
    def parse_product(self, response):
             ...
```

I try to connect the website with a VPN in another country it gives the following error.

```
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.

Your support ID is: ******
```

Do you have any suggestions except proxy?

Comment: This is called geo fencing. The web server is checking the IP address of the client that connects to it, and compares that to a list of known IP ranges located inside that country. You *cannot* circumvent that by changing your HTTP request. You have to use a proxy or VPN, so that the connection originates from within the country.

Comment: Okay man I think I will buy a proxy :( you can write your answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a meta tag to my spider and it solve my problem.

```
class CarrefoursaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'carrefoursa'
    allowed_domains = ['www.carrefoursa.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.carrefoursa.com/meyve/c/1015']
    meta={'proxy': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx'},
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE":"scrapy_logs/"+name+".log",
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY":False,
        "USER_AGENTS":None,
        "COOKIES_ENABLED":True,
        "COOKIES_DEBUG" : True
        }
    def parse(self,reponse):
        request = scrapy.Request(
                reponse.url, callback=self.parse_product,cookies={'Content-Language':'tr','currency': 'TRY', 'country': 'TR','lang': 'tr'}, dont_filter=True)
        yield request
        
    def parse_product(self, response):
             ...
```